# copied list change the original list (python)?

Tags: python, list, copy

Goal: I want to create a list, make a copy of it, and manipulate the copy while not affecting the original.

I created a toy example to show the problem. When I copy the listand append the copy, somehow this traces back to the original. How can I keep this from affecting the original?

```py
class testing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.array2 = self.array1

    def display1(self):
        print(self.array1)

    def display2(self):
        ary = self.array2
        ary.append(6)
        print(ary)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = testing()
    test.display1()
    test.display2()
    test.display1()
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The third result shows that the first list has the appended '6' that was only added to the copy list

Comment: FYI, they are *lists*, not arrays.

Comment: Nowhere do you copy your *list*. You simply assign the same list to a different variable

Answer (score 2):

You're very close.

Just add `.copy()` when you define `ary`.

So, in the first line of display2, use this instead
`ary = self.array2.copy()`

```
class testing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.array2 = self.array1

    def display1(self):
        print(self.array1)

    def display2(self):
        ary = self.array2.copy()
        ary.append(6)
        print(ary)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = testing()
    test.display1()
    test.display2()
    test.display1()
```

now returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As chepner notes, these are lists, not arrays. For Numpy arrays, you would want to use `ary = np.copy(self.array2)` to achieve the same result.